# Why mock doesn't patch passed class?

Tags: python, testing, mocking, pytest

I want to test if class extending `tkinter.Tk` is initialized with correct parameters. Imports work correctly. I can use both `main` and `Gui`, but I don't understand why do I get `AssertionError: Expected 'Gui' to be called once. Called 0 times.` with `mocked`. This statement `mocker.patch('bookmeister.gui.Gui')` seems to be correct for me if `from bookmeister.gui import Gui` works.

```
from bookmeister.__main__ import main
from bookmeister.gui import Gui

def test_run(mocker):
    mocker.patch.object(Gui, 'mainloop')
    mocked = mocker.patch('bookmeister.gui.Gui')
    spy = mocker.spy(Gui, '__init__')
    main()
    mocked.assert_called_once_with('Bookstore Manager', '600x470')
    spy.assert_called_once_with('Bookstore Manager', '600x470')
```

I have also tried to use `mocker.spy`, but then another error is displayed.

`AssertionError:
 Expected call: __init__('Bookstore Manager', '600x470')
 Actual call: __init__(<bookmeister.gui.Gui object .>, 'Bookstore Manager', '600x470')`

I have no idea how I can simulate `<bookmeister.gui.Gui object .>` in my test.

Could you please explain me how I can correct my code to test right initialization?

Comment: That depends on how you import `Gui` in the module to test - check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

Comment: I had to change `bookmeister.gui.Gui` to `bookmeister.__main__.Gui` in patch. Thank you, so much for useful information.